# Select a radiobutton

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get that when you click on a row in the table then the radio button on the same row will be selected.

Have anyone some suggestions for how this can be done?

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table id="simplehighlight" class="REW_table" style="width: 350px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" >
    <thead></thead>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="radio" id="RadioGroup1_0"></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="radio" id="RadioGroup1_0"></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="radio" id="RadioGroup1_0"></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="radio" id="RadioGroup1_0"></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="radio" id="RadioGroup1_0"></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#simplehighlight tr').hover(function(){
        $(this).children().addClass('datahighlight'); // Mark lightgray

        $(this).click(function(){
            $('#simplehighlight tr').children().removeClass('datahighlight_select'); // Remove all old blue mark
            $(this).children().addClass('datahighlight_select'); // Mark blue
        });

    },function(){
        $(this).children().removeClass('datahighlight'); // Remove lightgray
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#simplehighlight tr").click(function () {
    $(this).find("input:radio").prop("checked", true);
});
```

Using [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) with [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find) and binds to the click event using [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click)

Also note that your HTML as posted is invalid:

- Your `input` tags should be self-closing and,
- You've forgotten the `</td>` tag.
- Additionally, you have multiple elements on one page with the same `id` attribute, which is not allowed.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/yJ3RN/ (also corrects the HTML problems)